# Chances of a Desktop Bridge app getting published in the store

Tags: desktop-bridge

I am planning to create a UWP app which calls in a win32 exe for some tasks. Win32 exe will implement the functionalities which cannot be implemented with .net core.

**Will such an app be published in the store?**

I don't want to end up in a situation where I make the app and at the end the app is not allowed in the store.

Answer (score 1):

You can submit your info here and then discuss your planned submission with a dedicated consultant from Microsoft:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/projects/campaigns/desktop-bridge

Also feel free to hit me up directly for any quick questions (swick at Microsoft.com)

Comment: I did fill out that form 3-4 days back but I am yet to receive any communication from Microsoft. Generally how long does it take?

Comment: Did you get a mail to confirm your email address. Be sure to confirm this. If you have already done that and still haven't heard after 2 business days, please contact me directly and we'll clear this up.